# Loading state in Clerk/nextjs (isLoaded) is always true

Tags: next.js, clerk

I am using @clerk/nextjs and want to check whether user's session is fetching or not by this

`const { isSignedIn, isLoaded, user } = useUser();`

But isSignedIn is always false at initial and isLoaded is always true. How to check loading state of this ?

is there any clerk's hooks or workaround (except timeout) to check if user isSignedIn=false or it just Loading?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `useUser` hook returns `isLoaded: true` and `isSignedIn: false` at the same time only when `user` is `null` ([ref](https://github.com/clerkinc/javascript/blob/86531703949f5f9fa00d56893fda4e6eabddaeaa/packages/react/src/hooks/useUser.ts#L51))

So, if `isSignedIn` is `false` instead of `undefined` (indicates loading state), there will be no user object too.

You can check `isSignedIn` for an `undefined` to check if it is still loading. But probably something else is wrong with your code, hard to tell anything else with currently available information.

Comment: isSigned in is always false for both loading and non-user, there's no undefined value. user is always null for loading and non-user. isLoaded is always true.